# fdisk shows existing partition in brand new hdd

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, fdisk

I just bought a hard disk (Seagate ST2000DM001) and got from fdisk that it is already partitioned.

```
crown mnt # fdisk -l /dev/sdc

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x90ba1b1c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *        2048   488378644   244188298+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

It's been long since I got a new HDD, so I'm not sure if it is an expected result for fdisk -l.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might mount the partition and look at its contents. Maybe you discover that you've received a refurbished disk with lots of private data, or maybe the folks at Seagate just put an empty NTFS filesystem on the disk because Windows users do not know how to format a new disk.